# python привязка

Tags: python

Необходимо реализовать привязку программы к жесткому диску, как это реализовать? Перекопал весь интернет, не нашёл дельных советов

Comment: Поясните, что такое привязка к диску?

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий, при запуске программы, получается HWID ЖД и сравнивается с заданным заранее

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328732/11558617